# How to get the two highest values in a HashMap<Integer,String>, making a ranking

Tags: java

I have the following code:

```
public class Tester {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        HashMap<Integer,String> map = new HashMap<Integer,String>();

        map.put(1, "one");
        map.put(2, "twp");
        map.put(2, "two2");

        int highest = Integer.MIN_VALUE;
        String highestString = null;
        int secondHighest = Integer.MIN_VALUE;
        String secondHighestString = null;

        if (highest == Integer.MIN_VALUE){
            highest = Collections.max(map.keySet() );
            highestString = map.get(highest);
            map.remove(highest);
        }
        if (secondHighest == Integer.MIN_VALUE ){
            secondHighest = Collections.max(map.keySet() );
            secondHighestString = map.get(secondHighest);
            map.remove(secondHighest);
        }

        System.out.println(highest + highestString);
        System.out.println(secondHighest + secondHighestString);


    }

}
```

I cannot return the both 2 highest values, as I tried, because it seems to not be possible to remove only one value with the same key, and I also tried to swap them ( making a HashMap was also not the best option). Should I try to use any other kind of collection?

I also tried:

```
TreeSet<Tete> set = new TreeSet<Tete>();

    set.add(new Tete("name1", 1));
    set.add(new Tete("name2",4));
    set.add(new Tete("name3",4));
    set.add(new Tete("name4",12));

    System.out.println(set.size());
```

Assuming that the class "Tete" only carries one String and one Integer, the set size is only 3, not 4, as expected. And if I print every numbers, "name3" wont be printed, so I cannot return the 3 biggest values, for example, only "name4", "name2" and "name1" would appear, but "name3" is bigger than "name1"

Comment: Integer.MIN_VALUE returns the minimum value for an integer. (i.e.-2147483648)

Comment: Yes, it could be 0 too, I've just put the minium value because one of the values in the HashMap map could be negative

Comment: You're expecting to get `dois` and `dois2`? `HashMap` will overwrite `dois` with `dois2`. Note how keys are retrieved in a _set_, so only unique keys will be stored.

Comment: No I mean, it will give you the smallest value that you can ever set an integer to. Not the smallest in the array.

Comment: Take a look at `TreeSet` class with custom comparator. Create a custom class with key and value and add its instances to the TreeSet. TreeSet is always sorted hence you can take two elements from the top and they will be the highest. NOTE: TreeSet provide add, remove and contains operations at log(N) time.

Comment: @Keenle
It also wont work, if I try to add two objects with the same integer value, it will also delete the previous one, returning less numbers than expected (I'll put what i've tried to do in OP)

Comment: Should I assume there's no way to make a sort of "Ranking" with HashMaps? If so, what's a good way of doing it?

Comment: Regarding your most recent update: If your `Tete` class has an `equals` that makes `("nome2",4)` equal to `("nome3",4)`, then you still can't add them both the the set, because a `Set` requires that no two elements be equal according to the `equals` method.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To solve the ranking problem I would write a custom class, something like this:

```
public class TopsCollection<D> {

    private final TreeMap<Integer, List<D>> map 
        = new TreeMap<>((lhv, rhv) -> rhv.compareTo(lhv));

    public TopsCollection() {}

    public void add(Integer score, D name) {
        List<D> vals = map.get(score);
        if (vals == null) {
            vals = new ArrayList<>();
            map.put(score, vals);
        }
        vals.add(name);
    }

    public List<D> getTops(int n) {
        return map.
            values().
            stream().
            limit(n).
            reduce(new ArrayList<D>(), (lhv, rhv) -> {
                lhv.addAll(rhv);
                return lhv;
            });
    }
}
```

Usage:

```
TopsCollection<String> tc = new TopsCollection<>();
tc.add(12, "nome4");
tc.add(1, "nome1");
tc.add(4, "nome3");
tc.add(4, "nome2");

List<String> tops = tc.getTops(2); // contains 3 elements: nome4, nome3, nome2
```

**Remarks:**

This particular implementation can return any number of top highest ranks related entries.

Should be also noted that `add(...)` method takes time proportional to `log(n)` because TopsCollection backed by `TreeMap` class.

If needed `TopCollection` can implement `Collection<T>` interface to make it work as a real collection.

Answer (score 2):

Any `Map` (including `HashMap`) can only store one value for any key.  Thus, after your three `map.put` calls, there will be only two elements in your map: `[1,"Um"]` and `[2,"dois2"]`.  The value `"dois"` will no longer exist in the map.

If you really need to store multiple values for each key, the way to do this using the Java runtime is to have each key map to a list of values.

```
HashMap<Integer,ArrayList<String>> map = new HashMap<Integer,ArrayList<String>>();
```

This does mean that the code to add a value to the map, and to remove a value, is more complicated.  To add a value requires code like this:

```
ArrayList<String> list = map.get(key);
if (list == null) {
    list = new ArrayList<String>();
    map.put(key, list);
}
list.add(newValue);
```

Removing a value is similar: you need to get the list, then remove the value from the `ArrayList`, and remove the key from the map only if the `ArrayList`'s size is now 0.

Alternatives: There are "multi-map" collections in third-party libraries such as Apache Commons ([javadoc](https://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-collections/javadocs/api-3.2.1/org/apache/commons/collections/MultiMap.html)).  Or, as @Keenle suggested, you can use a set where the key is an object containing *both* the integer and the string.  You'd have to write the class for this object, but it would be very simple.

Comment: What I actually need is two keys for the same value, not , I expressed myself wrongly. For example, if I had a HashMap<String,Integer>, I would need to get the strings for which the Integers are the highest in the map. But if I have for example, two integers of value 5, I can only return one of the Strings, not both.

Comment: @Kerooker So in your original example, you want to return `"Um"` and `"dois"` (or `"dois2"`), and remove them from the map, but leave `"dois2"` (or `"dois"`) in the map?  Or do you want it to return `"dois"` and `"dois2"` and leave `"Um"` in the map?  I'm not really clear on what you need.