# Java - print max of key value pair with custom logic

Tags: java, hashmap

Lets assume I have a hashmap with data like :

```
Hello - 2
Help - 2
World - 1
```

I want to be able to print the top 2 based on the value, if the value is same for 2 objects then based on the key (ascending in this case). Is this possible only with a custom `comparator` object or are there better ways to get this done?

Comment: Does this solve your answer https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27537734/how-to-get-the-two-highest-values-in-a-hashmapinteger-string-making-a-ranking

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The requirement to have two comparison keys makes the solution non-trivial, but you can nevertheless specify the sorting order just by composing comparators returned by helper methods, saving you the trouble to write your own implementation.

The following shows a stream operation with in-lined comparator construction that performs the required selection.

```
List<Map.Entry<String, Integer>> result = map.entrySet().stream()
    .sorted(Map.Entry.<String, Integer>comparingByValue()
            .reversed()
            .thenComparing(Map.Entry::getKey))
    .limit(2)
    .collect(toList());
```

Comment: thanks for the answer but i am looking for something other than a custom comparator. just to know of there are better ways to do this.